# Do bitwise operators cause locks that normal comparisons don't?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL script that has been causing issues with deadlocks, and I'm wondering if there is some sort of special lock that is applied when doing a bitwise operation.

The offending query is this:

```
UPDATE pos.prices SET active = 1 WHERE NOT (Attributes & 1 = 1)
```

with column types active `BIT` and Attributes `TINYINT`.

The reason is that tons of other scripts with updates not including a bitwise AND (&) execute with no issues.  This is the only update with this operation and it is deadlocking.

The query it is deadlocking against is a large, periodic select with multiple joins that is grabbing a `SCHEMA` lock.

**Edit:** Would this query avoid the table scan?

```
UPDATE pos.prices SET active = 1 WHERE id in
(SELECT id FROM
(SELECT id, (Attributes & 1) as IsLocked FROM pos.prices) as t1
WHERE NOT IsLocked = 1)
```

Comment: One possible difference is that the bitwise test requires a table scan to evaluate the bitwise operation on every row. Indexes will be of no use for your example.

Comment: Well, you need a table lock to do an update and you're running your update across every record in your table that has an even numbered Attributes value so I guess it depends on how big your pos.prices table is. If it's large then it makes sense. Do the operations that run quickly have where criteria that is more limiting and can use an index?

Comment: @Love2Learn I don't know what qualifies as large, but the table is usually in the range of 500-2000 records.  Most other updates are either targeted at a specific row by its PK or at all rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any operation the does a calculation on a column in the where clause prevents the usage of an index for that column. That leads to a table scan. While a table scan does not necessarily produce deadlocks, it can significantly increase their probability.

Comment: If I put the calculation in a `SELECT` instead of a `WHERE` does that avoid the issue?  I've edited the question to show an example.

Comment: @MalcolmO'Hare I'd be surprised if that made any difference. The query optimiser has enough flexibility that the two versions could very well resolve to the same plan.